# NSMutableArray losing all of its objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I am making a function which allows you to read from a database and then puts the data into a `NSMutableArray` which it later returns for the user. Though for some reason when it is about to return the data the data is deleted from the array. Here is the code for the function:

```
+(NSMutableArray *) readFromDataBaseWithName:(NSString *)name withSqlStatement:(NSString *)sql {
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSMutableArray *rtn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *new = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int index = 0;
    NSString *filePath = [self copyDatabaseToDocumentsWithName:name];
    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStateMent = [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStateMent, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // loop through elements in row and put them into array
                const char *s = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, index);
                while (s) {
                    [new addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s]];
                    index++;
                    s = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, index);
                }
                [rtn addObject:new];
                [new removeAllObjects];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return rtn;
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep reusing `new`. You need to create individual arrays each time.

```
+(NSMutableArray *) readFromDataBaseWithName:(NSString *)name withSqlStatement:(NSString *)sql {
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSMutableArray *rtn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int index = 0;
    NSString *filePath = [self copyDatabaseToDocumentsWithName:name];
    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStateMent = [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStateMent, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // loop through elements in row and put them into array
                NSMutableArray *new = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                const char *s = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, index);
                while (s) {
                    [new addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s]];
                    index++;
                    s = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, index);
                }
                [rtn addObject:new];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why your code was giving you the results you were seeing?

Comment: was it because i was adding the array then deleting everything in the array that I added

Comment: Exactly. You were adding multiple references of the same array. When you called `removeAllObject` from that array, it of course resulted in the objects disappearing from all of the references.